# Serializing data in a backgroundworker - Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, backgroundworker

I am serializing a class with a binaryformatter and compressing the data with deflatestream. The save function is as follows and is called from a backgroundworker:

```
public static void save(System system, String filePath) 
{
    //Make filestream
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    try 
    {
        //Serialize offerte
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        DeflateStream cs = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress);

        bf.Serialize(cs, system);

        //Push through
        fs.Flush();
        cs.Flush();
        cs.Close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        var mess = e.Message;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        //Close
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

The class has a number of 'users'. With 100 users it takes 10 seconds and the file is 2MB. With 1000 users it gives an out-of-memory exception (the estimated size is 16MB). Can anyone see a problem here, or give suggestions how to solve this?
(I was first thinking the time on a background thread was causing this, it takes to long. But I have other background threads that can run longer.)

Comment: `System` is a terrible choice for type name.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any exceptions?  You are swallowing any that do happen, which could make tracking down issues hard.

Comment: Why are you swallowing exceptions?

Comment: It is not called system in realtime, just for the example. I have my breakpoint on the catch, just to catch up the exception and see what happends. It gives an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't disposing of your streams, which may be part of the problem, suggest:

```
public static void save(System system, String filePath) 
{
    //Make filestream
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))    
    {
        //Serialize offerte
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (DeflateStream cs = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress)) {

           bf.Serialize(cs, system);

           //Push through
           fs.Flush();
           cs.Flush();
           cs.Close();
       }
    }     
}
```

This also removes your exception swallowing, which would probably be a good thing.

Comment: It seems that this generates a nice file. Can you explain to me why using a using{} statement does not generate a out-of-memory exception?

Comment: Both of your streams implement IDisposable - for classes like this, it is recommended that you always Dispose of them after use, as they may have unmanaged resources that need to be released.  It is this 'tidying up' that may be helping you when you have large numbers of users.

Comment: Much better explanation in more depth here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was solved, but still getting out of memory exception!

Comment: You may need to add more details about how you are calling this and also some indication as to what the size of a single file is - not 100% clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You use several objects of classes that implement System.IDisposable

> If a designer implemented IDisposable he informs you that he might use scarce resources. You might get out of resources before the garbage collector collects the garbage.

In other words: whenever you use a class that implements System.IDisposable you should call Dispose() as soon as you don't need the class anymore. This is especially needed if you need the resources of the class for something else.

You use two Stream classes: FileStream and DeflateStream. They both implement IDisposable. If you don't call Dispose(), the garbage collector eventually will, but in the mean time the resources that these Streams use are not available for anyone else.

The most easy method to make sure that a Disposable object is disposed is by using the using statement:

```
using (var myStream = new FileStream(...))
{
    ... // use myStream
}
```

When the closing bracket is reached, myStream.Dispose() is called, effectively releasing all scarce resources it uses.

> This works on every method that is used to leave the {...} block, including break, return, and even Exceptions.

Therefore using is a very safe method: Dispose() will always be called.

By the way: Dispose() will also take care that the Streams are Flushed and Closed, so at the end of the using statement you don't have to Flush() and Close().